# Array name is random every time C# complex Json

Tags: c#, json

This is the Json I am working with:

```
{
  "field_1": 918237,
  "field_2": "test",
  "field_3": 918237,
  "field_4": [
    {
      "Type": "test",
      "field_5": {
        "id": "aasd812736",
        "time": "2018-03-29T20:34:33.910Z",
        "last_time": "2022-11-16T17:30:54.579Z",
        "ext": 123,
        "exp": 5,
        "id_full": "aasd8127367618253172",
        "moreId": 87162387,
        "version": "v1.5",
        "items": {
          "RANDOM ID_1": {
            "template": "ineedthis_1",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1",
                "owned": [
                  " lvl 1 ",
                  " lvl 2 ",
                  " lvl 3 ",
                  " lvl 4 ",
                  " lvl 5 "
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_2": {
            "template": "ineedthis_2",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1"
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_3": {
            "template": "ineedthis_3",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1",
                "owned": [
                  " lvl 2 ",
                  " lvl 3 ",
                  " lvl 4 ",
                  " lvl 5 "
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_4": {
            "template": "ineedthis_4",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1"
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_5": {
            "template": "ineedthis_5",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1"
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_6": {
            "template": "ineedthis_6",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1"
              }
            }
          },
          "RANDOM ID_7": {
            "template": "ineedthis_7",
            "attributes": {
              "lvl_at": 1,
              "has_at": true,
              "variants": {
                "channel": "progressive",
                "active": "lvl1",
                "owned": [
                  " lvl 2 ",
                  " lvl 3 "
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "stats": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "lifetime": 100,
            "book": false,
            "past_experience": [
              {
                "seas_id": 3,
                "seas_wi": 100,
                "seas_lv": 40,
                "book_lv": 30
              },
              {
                "seas_id": 4,
                "seas_wi": 310,
                "seas_lv": 5,
                "book_lv": 30
              },
              {
                "seas_id": 5,
                "seas_wi": 150,
                "seas_lv": 51,
                "book_lv": 32
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically, the `RANDOM ID_1 to 7` are randomly generated everytime by the API, I want to get the value from the `template` to a string for each one of the IDs and if there is a `variant` I want to get the maximum variant that is available, when available(Ex. ID_7 has max lvl 3 but ID_3 has max lvl 5).

It would be so much easier if the array name was not random for these. I've been searching the whole day on stackoverflow and other websites but can't seem to find anyone with a similar issue to this.

If you have answered this question before, please send me the link. Would appreciate it a lot!

I've tried

`var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);`

`Console.WriteLine(user.template);`

But this way it returns me the null exception for the `user` . Also thinking that I cannot check the variants this way.

Comment: So you want to deserialise `items` as a `Dictionary<string, [something] >`, then search the keys ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman yes, that would be helpful too, but i do not know how to name the random name

Answer (score -1):

Instead of dynamic , I prefer to use Parse

```
    var items = ((JObject)JObject.Parse(json)["field_4"][0]["field_5"]["items"]);

    List<Result> result = items.Properties().Select(x => new Result
    {
        Id = x.Name,
        Template = (string)x.Value["template"],
        MaxLevel = x.Value["attributes"]["variants"]["owned"] == null ?
                      "N/A" : x.Value["attributes"]["variants"]["owned"][x.Value["attributes"]["variants"]["owned"].Count() - 1].ToString().Trim()
    }).ToList();


public class Result
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Template { get; set; }
    public string MaxLevel { get; set; }
}
```

or you can use an anonymous object instead of class

result

```
[
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_1",
    "Template": "ineedthis_1",
    "MaxLevel": "lvl 5"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_2",
    "Template": "ineedthis_2",
    "MaxLevel": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_3",
    "Template": "ineedthis_3",
    "MaxLevel": "lvl 5"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_4",
    "Template": "ineedthis_4",
    "MaxLevel": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_5",
    "Template": "ineedthis_5",
    "MaxLevel": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_6",
    "Template": "ineedthis_6",
    "MaxLevel": "N/A"
  },
  {
    "Id": "RANDOM ID_7",
    "Template": "ineedthis_7",
    "MaxLevel": "lvl 3"
  }
]
```

Comment: I tried this, but i am getting this error, just like with the dynamic type
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: @Jim This code was tested and  is working properly. Recheck the json you posted, it could be different.

Comment: Here is the actual Json i am getting as a response from the API

https://pastebin.com/6HpXCsY3

I've changed the `field_4`, `field_5` names accordingly as well as the others, and i am getting the same error. In this json, the `lvl 1` `lvl 2` etc are `Stage1` `Stage2` etc

Comment: Edit: Just removed the MaxLevel and it works, but i still need to find how to have the information for the maxlevel

Comment: When do you have an error - using json you posted or a real json? All names that in my code should be the same in json.  For maxLevel you have to check ["attributes"]["variants"]["owned"]  exist After testing you can change them for a real json.

Comment: It's been a few days now, and i understand now how it works. I am just getting this error for the maxLevel:
"_System.ArgumentException: 'Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "owned". Int32 array index expected.'_"

What can that mean? When i google it, it looks like i am the first person with this error